Prisma-Turso-db Error in Next.js project. Driver Adapter `@prisma/adapter-libsql`, based on `sqlite`, is not compatible with the provider `postgres`
An error occurs when i start development server trying to connect to the database using a combination of prisma and turso-db . I tried to do everything according to the official documentation https://docs.turso.tech/sdk/ts/orm/prisma
, but I still get an error.
I tried to change the provider in the schema.prisma to libsql and sqlite, that didnt help.
GITHUB:https://github.com/nikitodeon/Error-prisma-turso.git
example.env
TURSO_AUTH_TOKEN="eyJhbGciOi....4LALvigvSfrXuUjbAg"
TURSO_DATABASE_URL="libsql://<name>.turso.io"

prisma-client.ts
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import { PrismaLibSQL } from "@prisma/adapter-libsql";
import { createClient } from "@libsql/client";


const libsql = createClient({
  url: process.env.TURSO_DATABASE_URL as string,
  authToken: process.env.TURSO_AUTH_TOKEN as string,
});


const adapter = new PrismaLibSQL(libsql);


const prisma = new PrismaClient({ adapter });

export { prisma };


schema.prisma
generator client {
    provider = "prisma-client-js"
    previewFeatures = ["driverAdapters"]
}

datasource db {
    provider  = "postgresql"
    url       = env("TURSO_DATABASE_URL") // uses connection pooling
    // directUrl = env("POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING") // uses a direct connection
}

model User {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

    fullName String
    email    String    @unique
    password String
    role     UserRole  @default(USER)
    verified DateTime?

    provider   String?
    providerId String?

    cart             Cart?
    orders           Order[]
    verificationCode VerificationCode?

    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Category {
    id       Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
    name     String    @unique
    products Product[]

    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Product {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

    name     String
    imageUrl String

    ingredients Ingredient[]
    items       ProductItem[]

    category   Category @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
    categoryId Int

    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model ProductItem {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

    price     Int
    size      Int?
    pizzaType Int?

    cartItems CartItem[]

    product   Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
    productId Int
}

model Ingredient {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

    name     String
    price    Int
    imageUrl String

    products  Product[]
    cartItems CartItem[]

    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Cart {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

    user   User? @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
    userId Int?  @unique

    items CartItem[]

    token String

    totalAmount Int @default(0)

    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model CartItem {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

    cart   Cart @relation(fields: [cartId], references: [id])
    cartId Int

    productItem   ProductItem @relation(fields: [productItemId], references: [id])
    productItemId Int

    quantity Int @default(1)

    ingredients Ingredient[]

    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Order {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

    user   User? @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
    userId Int?

    token String

    totalAmount Int
    status      OrderStatus
    paymentId   String?

    items Json

    fullName String
    email    String
    phone    String
    address  String
    comment  String?

    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model VerificationCode {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

    user   User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
    userId Int  @unique

    code String

    createdAt DateTime @default(now())

    @@unique([userId, code])
}

model Story {
    id              Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
    previewImageUrl String

    items StoryItem[]

    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
}

model StoryItem {
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

    storyId Int
    story   Story @relation(fields: [storyId], references: [id])

    sourceUrl String

    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
}

enum OrderStatus {
    PENDING
    SUCCEEDED
    CANCELLED
}

enum UserRole {
    USER
    ADMIN
}

package.json
{
  "name": "next-pizza",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "prisma:push": "prisma db push",
    "prisma:studio": "prisma studio",
    "prisma:seed": "prisma db seed",
    "postinstall": "prisma generate"
  },
  "prisma": {
    "seed": "ts-node --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"} prisma/seed.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.4.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-checkbox": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-popover": "^1.0.7",
    "@radix-ui/react-select": "^2.0.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-slider": "^1.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/qs": "^6.9.15",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.7",
    "drizzle-orm": "^0.38.3",
    "lucide-react": "^0.376.0",
    "next": "14.2.3",
    "next-auth": "^4.24.7",
    "nextjs-toploader": "^1.6.12",
    "qs": "^6.12.1",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dadata": "^2.23.1",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.51.5",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "react-insta-stories": "^2.7.0",
    "react-use": "^17.5.0",
    "resend": "^3.2.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.3.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "vaul": "^0.9.0",
    "zod": "^3.23.8",
    "zustand": "^4.5.2",
    "@libsql/client": "^0.14.0",
    "@prisma/adapter-libsql": "^6.1.0",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "drizzle-kit": "^0.30.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.3",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5",
    "prisma": "^5.4.2"
  }
}


I've tried different versions of dependencies in package.json
